# Unmanaged C++ use c# dll which throws exception

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have an unmanaged C++ project.
Recently I added a DLL written in C# (wasn't able to find an implementation in C++). The C# project is configured to build as DLL.

I'm using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress in unmanaged C++ to call an exported method in C#. For C# I'm using RGiesecke.DllExport to export a method from DLL.

The DLL project throws an FileNotException. I'm using the try{}catch in C# to catch the exception, but I receive an error in unmanaged C++ which breaks the application. error code is: 0xE0434352.
I know I should fix the problem so exception is not thrown, but the problem is that some exceptions may be thrown at runtime and I need to be sure the unmanaged code is not broken because of this.

Comment: That's the ultimate failure mode of Gieseke's utility.  Managed code likes throwing exceptions, you can't get the details in native C++.  And the most basic mishap, like file-not-found, gets completely undiagnosable.  Try/catch in the C# code is important but this is the kind of exception that's thrown by the jitter, *before* the C# code can start running.  You'll have to putz around to get somewhere, changing the Debugger Type from Auto to Mixed can help.  Custom-hosting the CLR or COM is the better mousetrap, at least you can use IErrorInfo.

Comment: Converting your Dll's functions to be exposed via COM gets IErrorInfo and Exception-to-HRESULT mapping.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to convert dll to a Windows Application so I can execute it as a different process. This should fix the problem.